# Elevate workflow to app permissions in site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

We have a workflow on a list in a subsite. In this workflow we need to read/write data in another list in the root site. We elevated the workflow permission on the subsite and it works as expected.
The problem comes when we save the site as a template and then create other sites with that template. The workflow elevation is not persisted so the read/write REST calls fail (FORBIDDEN).

Is it possible to persist the workflow elevation in the site template, or are there other solutions for our requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, this is impossible because SharePoint registers a new App ID for workflows engine on each subsite.